# Getting name from POST after setting submit button name with a for loop

Tags: php

I've got a loop to create a couple submit buttons, which I then want to be able to use via `$_POST`.

It's for a simple fake webshop type project, if you click on a `submit` button underneath a particular item it will run a function to add that item to the shopping cart.

First up, my for loop that uses `$count` (which checks the rows in a table).
Then I loop through that so `name=1` through however many rows I have.

```
$count = count($listGames);
 for ($i=1; $i <= $count ; $i++) {
   echo "<form method=POST><td><input type=submit name=$i value='Add to cart'></form></td>";
 }
```

Now I thought that I could do it with an `if` statement, but I'm not sure how to continue. I thought maybe `$i` inside `$_POST[]`, but of course outside of the for loop it will have a fixed value. I'm also not sure whether I can use the if statement inside the for loop so if I write `$_POST[$i]` it does iterate through.

```
if (isset($_POST[''])) {
 //add the item to the cart
 addToCart();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to send your `sku` values from your `$listGames` (assuming that is what these are) into a hidden field. Also, it would be helpful to use some action words to easily process instructions. Finally, watch your html syntax, your open `td` appears to be in the wrong spot:

```
$listGames = [
    [
        'sku'=>'item101',
        'price'=>'85.00'
    ],
    [
        'sku'=>'item102',
        'price'=>'79.00'
    ]
];

$count = count($listGames);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { ?>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
            <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="<?php echo $listGames[$i]['sku'] ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
        </form>
    </td>
<?php
 }
```

To process the post:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case('add'):
            addToCart($_POST['sku']);
            break;
        case('remove'):
            remove($_POST['sku']);
            break;
        case('clear'):
            clearCart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That was exactly what I wanted to do. The answer was so simple in the end. Also, the HTML syntax inside loops is something that always confuses me after a while.

Comment: If you feel my answer was correct please accept the answer so the question is not let open and unsolved. Also it is fine to have a bunch of forms for adding to cart, that is normal, as long as the HTML is valid.